# How do i make 3 monitors into one big monitor?

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

I have 3 1920*1080 monitors and I want them to be like one big monitor. I have tried to use xrandr but I have not gotten it to work. I am also very new to ubuntu and linux so I have no idea what i am doing. I have a 6900xt from AMD as my gpu and a amd cpu with no graphics.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and also, are you using regular Ubuntu or some flavor?

Comment: Normal ubuntu is what I am using.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 0):

The "standard way" is to get into
Settings > Display
and arrange the screens such that they form the setup you wish for.

*hit Win/Super key, begin to type 'Settings'  and click the matching cog-wheel icon...*

Comment: In settings there is no setting that does what I want. I want something like AMD eyeinfinity or Nvidia surround.

Comment: To clarify the above: Generally you will have a "frame" per display, each of which can be moved about in relation to the others. Are you aware of that? *(I can't provide images as I'm on a laptop, single display)*